# Query result shows unwanted SQL SUM formula text in PHP/HTML display

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table 'marks' with fields Q1mark, Q2mark, Q3mark . . . Q50mark corresponding to the 50 questions in an exam.

I want to display how many marks each question attracted, and I'd like to order the questions by difficulty.

So I loop through 50 and put the key=>value pairs in a HTML table:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=50; $i++)
 {

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT (SUM(Q".$i."mark)) FROM marks");
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      foreach ($results as $result) 
          { 
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($result as $key=>$value)
                  { 
                echo '<td>'; echo $key; echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>'; echo $value; echo '</td>';

              } 
        echo '</tr>';
              }   
    }
```

What I get is:

```
------------------------
| (SUM(Q1mark)) |   18 |
| (SUM(Q2mark)) |   20 |
| (SUM(Q3mark)) |   8  |
| (SUM(Q4mark)) |   12 |
------------------------
```

but **what I want** is:

```
----------------
| Q3mark |  8  |
| Q4mark |  12 |
| Q1mark |  18 |
| Q2mark |  20 |
----------------
```

How do I get rid of the displayed formula text?, And order the data by difficulty?

Comment: You said your columns are named `Q1, Q2 etc.`. But in `SUM()` function you call `SUM(Q1mark)` instead of `SUM(Q1)`.

Comment: `echo`'ing HTML and variables like that will get extremely confusing later on. Just close the PHP tags and reopen them when you need to do something substantial. You can make use `<?=` and `?>` to `echo` out when you have closed the PHP tags.

Comment: My apologies! New to this. I'll amend now! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Gee I don't know... `(SUM(Q".$i."mark)) as Q$i` ?

Comment: Thank you, @ Funk Forty Niner! I had tried AS . . . with other things but it wouldn't work form me. Much appreciated. Can you help with ordering the data by $value?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to store all the result in a 2d array.

```
$final_result = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=50; $i++)
 {

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT (SUM(Q".$i."mark)) FROM marks");
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $final_result[] = $results;

 }
sort($final_result);
for($i=0;$i<count($final_result);$i++){
    echo $final_result[$i][“Q”.$i.”mark”];
}
```

Have a look at sorting arrays in PHP
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

Comment: Thanks, but there's no output when I do that. No error thrown, just white screen.

Comment: Please check the error_log of apache and post it here.

Comment: It throws a Warning:  
Warning: AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant \x93Q\x94 - assumed '\x93Q\x94' in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xx/httpdocs/php/xxx/xxx.php on line 56\n

Line 56 is echo $final_result[$i][“Q”.$i.”mark”];

Answer (score 0):

I'll close this question with an answer to the question posed in the question title that was supplied in a comment, otherwise it'll appear unanswered.

To get of the SUM formula text I need to SELECT the result AS . . . and use the variable $i in the column name:

```
(SUM(Q".$i."mark)) AS Q$i
```

I'll open a new question with a tighter focus on the other problem I mentioned, namely ordering the query results.